# Sending an email that extracts _input type="number"_ (in PHP)

Tags: php, email, input

I've got [this page](http://www.bendana.it/it/acquisti.php), in which you can calculate (by clicking over "Clicca qui per..") the price and the total number of the pieces needed. On the bottom of the page, I put a form to write the personal details.
Now, I'd like to send an email where I can **visualize** - in addition to the personal details - **the numbers that appear on the form**, once the calculations are made.

This is the **personal details form**:

```
    function formulario()
    {if(!isset($_POST['invia']))

    echo "<div id=\"form_wrapper_wrapper\">
    <div id=\"form1\">
        <h1>CONTATTI</h1>
        <form name=\"contatti\" action=\"acquisti.php\" method=\"post\">
            <table>
                <tr><td>nome e cognome/ditta*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"ditta\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo nome e cognome, o il nome della tua ditta\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>p.iva*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"piva\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui la tua partita IVA\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>c.f.*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"cf\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo codice fiscale\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>referente (come sei venuto a conoscenza di Bendana)</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"ref\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui come sei venuto a conoscenza di Bendana (facoltativo)\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>email*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"email\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo  indirizzo e-mail\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>indirizzo*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"via\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo indirizzo\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>cap*</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"cap\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo paese\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>città</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"citta\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui la tua città\"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>telefono</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"tel\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo numero di telefono\" required></td></tr>
                <tr><td>fax&nbsp;</td><td><input class=\"tabella\" type=\"text\" name=\"fax\" placeholder=\"Scrivi qui il tuo numero fax\"></td></tr>
            </table>
            <p id=\"obbligatorio\">I campi contrassegnati con l'asterisco sono obbligatori.</p>
    </div>
    <div id=\"form2\">
            <table>
                <tr><td></td><td><input id=\"cancella\" type=\"reset\" name=\"cancella\" value=\"Cancella\"><input id=\"invia\" type=\"submit\" name=\"invia\" value=\"Invia\"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>"; }
```

and this is the form where you can **put the number of pieces you need** (let's just look at the first line):

```
    <table class="tg" style="position: relative; right: -12px;">
      <tbody>
      <tr style="background-color: lightgrey;">
        <th id="art">articolo</th>
        <th id="art">cm.</th>
        <th id="art">kg.</th>
        <th id="art">taglia</th>
        <th id="art">costo unitario</th>
        <th id="art">quantità</th>
        <th id="art" style="border-right: #8B2300 2px solid;">sommano</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e">001.25-03.01</th>
        <th class="tg-031e">25</th>
        <th class="tg-031e">3-5</th>
        <th class="tg-031e">XXXS</th>
        <th class="tg-031e" style="text-align: right;padding-right: 27px;">8,50 €</th>
        <th class="tg-031e"><input name="num1" type="number" value="<? echo $num1;?>"></th>

        <th class="tg-031e" style="border-right: #8B2300 2px solid;">

        <?php

    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $parz1 = $num1 * 8.50;

    if (!$num1 || !is_numeric($num1) || $num1 < 0)

    {

    print "/";

    }

    else

    {

    print $parz1; } ?></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you have issues with some specific problem?

Comment: what you want to extract and show your value to extract

Comment: I'm not able to see, on the email that I send, the $num1 and the $parz1.
I see something like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/10h7qds.jpg